# Last 6 consecutive Sundays data

Tags: mysql, sql

How to get data for last 6 consecutive Sundays/Mondays?

Something like this

```
 +----------+---------+-------+                                                      
 |date      | Day     |sales  |                                                
 +----------+---------+-------+   
 |17-Jul-21 | Sunday  | 10    |                                            
 |10-Jul-21 | Sunday  | 30    |   
 |03-Jul-21 | Sunday  | 40    |  
 |26-Jun-21 | Sunday  | 20    |  
 |19-Jun-21 | Sunday  | 70    |  
 |12-Jun-21 | Sunday  | 20    |  
 +----------+---------+-------+
```

Comment: In the input table, do you have the sales totaled by day already, or can you have several rows for each date and you need to sum them over each day in the same query?

Comment: `MySQL`, `Oracle` and `Snowflake` are completely different databases. Please, specify exactly one DBMS you interested in (or two in case of migration or something similar). And provide sample data for this output

Comment: Is this for MySQL, Oracle, or Snowflake? Please delete the tags that don't apply.

Comment: Welcome to the site, Arun - we're ready to answer, but need to know what language you are using to be able to do so, or maybe what program you are using so we can guess. by leaving the `sql` tag in place, do you mean you are using `T-SQL` (perhaps in SQL Server Management Studio)?

Comment: i will be using mySQL

Comment: In input table the data is at date level and each date is summed, (like month to date data)

Comment: Show us the source table with (fake) data sample, your attempted query and please specify MySQL version. You want the date output to be exactly like `12-Jun-21` instead of the standard format like `2021-06-12`?

Comment: It can be of any date format , and regarding data it is at date level and from current data need to pick last 6 sundays and regarding SQL It can be any latest version.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
SELECT SalesDate, DAYNAME(SalesDate), SalesValue 
  FROM mytable 
 WHERE DAYNAME(SalesDate)='Sunday'
ORDER BY SalesDate DESC
LIMIT 6;
```

Using [DAYNAME()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayname) function to filter day and then order by date descending and add limit 6 to get the last 6 "Sunday" occurrence.

[Demo fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3fe2697e8b423e7fba490e8728db8733)

**Edit:**

To get 6 latest data for each day, you can assign `ROW_NUMBER()` for the last 6 order by `SalesDate` descending and partitioned by day name. Something like this:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM
(SELECT SalesDate, DAYNAME(SalesDate) Dayn, SalesValue,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY DAYNAME(SalesDate) ORDER BY SalesDate DESC) rn
FROM mytable) A
WHERE rn <= 6
ORDER BY Dayn, rn;
```

[Updated fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d41bffc369ba521cf38d76d94d211038)

Comment: how to do it for all the days i.e I want last 6 sundays sales, last 6 monday sales, last 6 tuesday sales and so on , as UNION won't work with ORDER BY and LIMIT.

Comment: Thanks @FaNo_FN, The logic is working fine, and what about if I need to find the average only for those last 6 days is there any work around for that

Comment: Try the last query in this fiddle https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=95362a899c9576fcd3ea538b378bab00

Comment: Thanks for the help, @FaNo_FN , the query is working as expected

Comment: Glad I could help @Arun. If this suggestion solved your issue, please consider to mark as accepted answer. A question with an accepted answer can help others having similar issue to find a convincing solution. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

In PostgreSQL it could be something like

```
-- for sunday
SELECT 
  date, 
  To_Char(date, 'day') as Day, 
  SUM(sales) 
FROM <table>
WHERE date >= now() - interval (6 weeks) 
AND EXTRACT(DOW FROM date) = 0
GROUP BY date;

-- for monday
SELECT 
  date, 
  To_Char(date, 'day') as Day, 
  SUM(sales) 
FROM <table>
WHERE date >= now() - interval (6 weeks) 
AND EXTRACT(DOW FROM date) = 1
GROUP BY date;

-- for tuesday
SELECT 
  date, 
  To_Char(date, 'day') as Day, 
  SUM(sales) 
FROM <table>
WHERE date >= now() - interval (6 weeks) 
AND EXTRACT(DOW FROM date) = 2
GROUP BY date;

-- ....
```